# overriding a function in coldfusion

Tags: inheritance, coldfusion, lucee

I have a function named as `OnSubmit` in two `CFCs`,

one is BASE.cfc and other is `PageUsed.cfc` . the function is different in `base.cfc` and `pageused.cfc` , b**ut the name is name and arguments are same.**

there is a third CFC named as UserObject.cfc invoked by passing a method name as Basic which returns the `PageUsed.cfc` object and method is called `OnSubmit`,

it should basically call the `Onsubmit` function in the `pageUsed` but it is calling the `Base.cfc` `OnSubmit` Function

what is going wrong

any idea?

Do i need to use SUPER, but super is used for some other purpose as i read

Comment: Does `PageUsed.cfc` extend `base.cfc`? Are you sure that function `basic()` is returning `PageUserd.cfc`? Can you do a `getMetaData()` on the returned object to verify?

Comment: getmetadata on the which cfc, the userobject.cfc

Comment: Set some variable to equal the result of the function `UserObject.basic()`. That is the function returning the object containing the expected `onSubmit()` function. You need to verify that the function is returning the correct object, which it seems it isn't.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code from UserObject.cfc that invokes the OnSubmit function.

Answer (score 2):

Components often extend other components and you do this explicitly in the component declaration.

```
<component extends="some.other.component">
```

In your case if you are doing `<component name="pageused" extends="base">` then in the pageused comonent you may have.

```
function onSubmit() {

}
```

Calling onSubmit like `pageUsed.onSubmit()` will run that function. If you want to run the onSubmit inside the base you could add the following to pageused.

```
function onSubmit() {
    super.onSubmit(); //Calling onSubmit in base.cfc
}
```

What is confusing about your question is this part:

> there is a third CFC named as UserObject.cfc invoked by passing a
> method name as Basic which returns the PageUsed.cfc object and method is called OnSubmit,

I get there is a userObject.cfc but can you share the code of where that is because it appears that that part is probably not working how you think it is. Especially confusing is you are passing a name "basic" but returning "pageUsed". Why wouldn't it return basic?

Comment: i think my question is not understood, i know inheritance, extends

Comment: I am trying to create one comman function to initiate other external component calls in a struct an if they exist in the scope, do not call them again,